# UIViewTransitions with wrong orientation

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I have prepared the storyboard shown in the picture: the app needs to work only in landscape (right). The orientation of the various controllers is set via the 'simulated metric' field.

When I move from the first controller to the second one, the sliding transition has the correct 'orientation': the content flows horizontally in landscape mode.

When I move from the second controller back to the first one, the sliding transition is wrong. It is displayed like if it were in portrait mode.

All the view controllers (and the project settings) specify landscape right as the only acceptable orientation.

[image: Storyboard]

[image: Project settings]

[image: Methods in the UIViewControllers]

The push from the first to the second is activated by a GestureRecognizer (swipe left): it is managed directly from the Storyboard (I added a GestureRecognizer on the view, etc.).

The pop from the second to the first view is done programmatically. I have a GestureRecognizer for the Swipe Right event and the pop is requested in the IBAction method.

[image: Pop to previous controller]

Is there anyone who can explain me the reason of its behaviour?

Comment: How are you moving from first-to-second ? Modal? or Simple Push?

Comment: I added the info to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest create a class of type `UINavigationController` , put all the rotation code inside that class, assign the class to `StoryBoard UINavigationController`, remove the rotation code from `ViewController`, it should work.

Comment: Quite a lot of work. Isn't there a simple 'anything' to do in order to force the Navigation controller to respect the only orientation supported?

Comment: This is the simplest way, it won't even take 1 minute to do.

Comment: Not you need to study the logic of UINavigationController and how it manages the animations :-)